# Font size on html table different on iPhone and Mac/PC

Tags: iphone, html, css, fonts, size

I have a table on my website with some text inside it. I have looked at it on both my iPhone, My Mac and my PC but the font size on the iPhone is much bigger than the font size on the Mac and PC. I have tried setting the css property font-size but it doesn't change. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to target smartphones or any other handheld devices using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries/) and then set an appropriate font-size.

You could for example do something like this to target your iPhone :

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```